# I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have added spring-web.4.0.jar in classpath. It contains the class - org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext. but when I try to run it in eclipse it shows me an error : `org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext`.
How to resolve this error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
 ... 21 more

Answer (score 17):

Choosing "Clean..." from the server contextual menu helped me get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try clean and rebuild your eclipse project, because sometimes eclipse gets out of date.

Alternatively, if this doesn't help, you need to verify that the runtime path indeed points to the correct jar, and that the jar does indeed contain the `WebApplicationContext.class` and is readable.

To see the runtime path, use the debug view (Window - Views- Debug), right click to view properties.

Find the jar and open it with a normal zip viewer to see if the file reads correctly.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt project. But its still showing the same error.

Comment: Did you also clean and republish to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem can be almost literally anything, but here are a few weird things to check:

- Maven dependencies with `test` or `provided` scope that should be normal scope
- Spring XML files have schema versions that don't match framework version (3.0 or 4.0)
- Spring XML references "https://" instead of "http://" or vice-versa (depends on version)
- `web.xml` file containing `${}` references not compatible with chosen web server
- Conflicting version of very core libraries such as Jackson, Servlet API, spring-*
- Misconfigured or missing or incompatible loggers: slf4j, log4j, jcl
- Mixing of old and new: jdk version, spring version, dependency versions, IDE, server
- Maven dependencies not showing up in Deployment Assembly (this one went away with upgrades)
- Stale or locked jarfiles... may require a reboot, tomcat "Clean..." not enough
- Missing required `-D` or environment variables

My application ended up with several of these all wrong one after another.

The exception is misleading. Setting a debugger breakpoint on the exception sometimes helps.